# What is the class attributes name spcecifically called?

Tags: html, css, class, syntax

```
<p class="name"></p>
```

I know the selector .name references the class. Would it be called a property, value, selector?

Comment: It would be called .class `selector`

Comment: `.class` is a selector, `class` is an attribute on the `html` element and the `name` would be the attribute value.

Comment: how do you gray block your text like that?

Comment: Read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

It is a selector.
Read about selectors in w3schools

> https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_selectors.asp

and MDN :

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_Selector

But in the HTML it is a property for each tag.

Comment: Consider not linking to that site. Good SEO. Terribly maintained content (some sections are much worse). Resources like MDN are much more curated and reputable.